# Retrieve Source in Manifest Not pulling in from Trailhead Org

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, manifest

I have a new trailhead org.

I have used the SFDX to `Create Project with Manifest` option. This generated the following XML.

I have set the trailhead as the Default org and authorized it. When I right click the package.xml and select `Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org` I get zero results. How do we go about troubleshooting this. I can see the ApexClasses from the super badge that I'm attempting to use, but they are not coming down to my VS code instance.

Additionally, I have also turned on the `Dev Hub` option in the Trailhead playground.

Any suggestions? I'm also concerned that this is a bigger issue as I have live orgs that have had problems. Thanks for the help.

File structure is standard for a trail head playground:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <version>49.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: I just read this article: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1293 looks like you have to explicitly state the apex class.

Comment: I'm able to use this package.xml and retrieve source by following the same steps mentioned in your question. Have you tried updating SFDX or VS Code? Have you tried on a different org or a different computer?

Comment: I've confirmed all are up to date. I believe it may be specific to the managed package of the trailhead project. That appears to be the issue on github that I posted in the previous comment. But I'm not getting any custom objects down. Not sure if this is a feature or a bug. Will test later tonight with my own custom objects

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be the Managed Package that Salesforce requires you to use for the LWC Specialist Super Badge. This is good to know, but would have been good for them to include a way to to get the package classes and objects down to VS Code.

But here you can see that it's still working as intended with custom objects that I create in the org, but managed package objects and standard objects are not coming down. This makes sense from a managed package perspective, but still would be good for SF to provide a "Retrieve the objects and classes by name as you complete tasks. Managed package components are not retrievable by wild cards."

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to reaffirm that my issue with this was related to a Managed Package as well, for the Apex Specialist Superbadge.

I just had to include the name of the file in between

```
<members></members>
```

...exactly as the file is referred to in the Org.

For example

```
<types>
    <members>MaintenanceRequest</members>
    <name>ApexTrigger</name>
</types>
```